# Filter a string that ends with exact substring

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use select-string to filter a string ends with exactly substring, but I cannot get the expected result.

Example pattern is "Caption:Amount"

```
Get-Content $TestFile |
    Select-String -Pattern "Caption:Amount" -CaseSensitive |
    Set-Content $NewFile
```

```
1. ABC Caption:Amount
2. BCD Caption:Amount Including VAT
3. XYZ Caption:Amount
4. PQR Caption:Amount Excluding VAT
```

My expected result are 1. and 3. only, but it show all 4 lines

Comment: The regex pattern for the end of a string or a line is the Dollar sign "**$**". So your pattern should be `"Caption:Amount$"`

Comment: Alternatively use `$_.EndsWith('Caption:Amount')` in a `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: Another alternative is to use a wildcard `-clike` comparison: `Get-Content $TestFile | Where-Object { $_ -clike "*Caption:Amount" }`. (`-like` is Case Insensitive; `-clike` is Case Sensitive)

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. It is working :)

Comment: Please consider writing an answer about how you solved your question and marking it as solved.